# requirejs load external script in the head

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

This My html Head:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>vente-privee.com</title>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Modules/lib/jquery-1.8.3.js")"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//url/otherScript.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Modules/config.js")"></script>
    <script data-main="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Modules/main")" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Modules/requirejs/require.js")"></script>
    </script>
</head>
```

I need to declare jquery and otherScript Syncrounously in the header.
In require.js, I need also to use the lib jquery (the same declared in the head), I don't need to reload an other version.

How Can I configure My Path?

Now I'm doing like this:

```
var require = {
    paths: {
        // local
        "jquery": "lib/jquery-1.8.3",
        "jquery.validate": "lib/jquery.validate",
        "jquery.validate.unobtrusive": "lib/jquery.validate.unobtrusive",
  },

    shim: {
        "jquery.validate": {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "jQuery.validator"
        },
        "jquery.validate.unobtrusive": {
            deps: ["jquery.validate"],
            exports: "jQuery.validator.unobtrusive"
```

So I reload Jquery 2 times, How can I reference the jquery loaded in the head?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you re-arranged your scripts to something like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Modules/requirejs/require.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Modules/lib/jquery-1.8.3.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//url/otherScript.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Modules/config.js")"></script>
<script>
    require("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Modules/main")");
</script>
```

This is not using the `data-main` attribute of the require script; instead it `require`s the main module directly (this may need trivial tweaking, depending on the contents of `main.js`, but I hope you get the point). This way jQuery will register itself to AMD, since RequireJS is loaded first and you do *NOT* need the path:

```
"jquery": "lib/jquery-1.8.3", // DELETE THIS!
```

By the way there is a stray `</script>` tag in your code above... (last line before `</head>`)